# Evaluating/executing strings dynamically in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

Is there any way of dynamically checking and setting parameters of the agents in AnyLogic by evaluating/executing strings?

My case:

- I have parking lots numbered from 0 to 200, named as parkingLot0, parkingLot1,...,parkingLot200 (each with capacity of 1).
- I have an agent called DetachedTrailer.
- I want to find an empty parking slot for the arriving DetachedTrailer and set agent.parking to that parkingLot.
- I do not want to do this manually one-by-one, instead would like to have a short loop that would do the trick.

I try using executeExpression, but it throws error saying
*Exception during discrete event execution:

root:

null*

Please see the function body of the screenshot below.

Unfortunately the documentation does not have much information about executeExpression. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the expression you need to do the following:

put all your parking spots in a collection, for this example i will put the network itself in a variable

the variable will be of type RoadNetwork and will have initial value roadNetwork... let's call this variable rn

then on the expression...

```
CodeValue myCode = new CodeValue(this,"rn.getParkingLots().get(0).nFree()");
```

This will work. You can do the same with parkingLot0, put it in a variable called pl0 of type ParkingLot with initial value parkingLot0 and the expression will look like this:

```
  CodeValue myCode = new CodeValue(this,"pl0.nFree()");
```

This will work aswell

Comment: Thank you Felipe! This was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

would this work? Remembering that your road network is a network that you can use. The roadNetwork is automatically created when you create your first road, and the network includes the parking spots.

```
ParkingLot pl=findFirst(roadNetwork.getParkingLots(),x->x.nFree()>0);
agent.parking=pl;
```

why would you do this executeExpression at all?
Do you want it for general puporses or to solve this particular problem?

Comment: Thank you Felipe, this resolves this particular case. However, I would like to understand why for example the code below throws error ("root:null").
`CodeValue myCode = new CodeValue(this,"parkingLot0.nFree()");
myCode.execute();`